# Is there a new version of the partnerDFACheck for Adobe Analytics using AppMeasurement

Tags: adobe-analytics

I have been in the process of migrating our existing Tag Management code using s_code to the new fancy Dynamic Tag Management system using AppMeasurement.
Most things work, but we have a plug-in, not listed on Adobes list of plugins:
https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/plugins_support.html
At the moment we have version 1.0:`s.  partnerDFACheck = new Function("cfg", ""
+ "var s=this,c=cfg.visitCookie,src=cfg.clickThroughParam,scp=cfg.searchCenterParam,p=cfg.newRsidsProp,tv=cfg.tEvar,dl=',',cr,nc,q,g,gs,i,j,k,fnd,v=1,t=new Date,cn=0,ca=new Array,aa=new Array,cs=new A"
+ "rray;t.setTime(t.getTime()+1800000);cr=s.c_r(c);if(cr){v=0;}ca=s.split(cr,dl);aa=s.split(s.un,dl);for(i=0;i<aa.length;i++){fnd = 0;for(j=0;j<ca.length;j++){if(aa[i] == ca[j]){fnd=1;}}if(!fnd){cs[cn"
+ "]=aa[i];cn++;}}if(cs.length){for(k=0;k<cs.length;k++){nc=(nc?nc+dl:'')+cs[k];}cr=(cr?cr+dl:'')+nc;s.vpr(p,nc);v=1;}q=s.wd.location.search.toLowerCase();q=s.repl(q,'?','&');g=q.indexOf('&'+src.toLow"
+ "erCase()+'=');gs=(scp)?q.indexOf('&'+scp.toLowerCase()+'='):-1;if(g>-1){s.vpr(p,cr);v=1;}else if(gs>-1){v=0;s.vpr(tv,'SearchCenter Visitors');}if(!s.c_w(c,cr,t)){s.c_w(c,cr,0);}if(!s.c_r(c)){v=0;}r"
+ "eturn v>=1;");`

Not a pretty site.
After de-ubfuscating this and debugging I could find out that a required property of the s object (un), doesn't exist anymore in the AppMeasurement s object.

Does anyone have experience with this or have a newer version.

A google search doesn't give me anything useful, only a few references of use with the old s_code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there were a number of breaking changes with AM.

`s.un` is just the RSIDs being passed in. You should be able to replace it with `s.account` without issue.

`s.wd` is a window reference, and is now `s.w`

Those should be the only 2 references that need updating. I haven't seen an updated version of the plugin, but you could always ask client care for it too.